# Proving using the definitions of "strictly dominated by" and "dominated by"

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $A, B,$ and $C$ be sets.
If $A$ is strictly dominated by $B$ and $B$ is dominated by $C$, then $A$ is strictly dominated by $C$.

I need to prove this using the definitions of "dominated by" (there exists an injection from $A$ to $B$) and "strictly dominated by" ($A$ is dominated by $B$ and $A$ is not numerically equivalent to $B$).

I tried to do this by using an injection $f: A\rightarrow B$ and another injection $g: B\rightarrow C$, and then using a function $h: A\rightarrow C$ defined by $h(x)=g(f(x))$, which makes it an injection. However, I still need to show that $A$ is not numerically equivalent to $C$ ($h$ is not a bijection).

I feel like I'm doing it wrong, can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $h(x)=g(f(x))$ is a bijection. Then it is surjective. This implies that $g$ is surjective, hence bijecive.

Now, try to show that this implies that $f$ is bijective too (composing with $g^{-1}$), contradicting the hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

First, it should be $g(f(x))$ instead of $f(g(x))$, the latter doesn't makes sense (look at the domains and codomains). Look at cardinalities: if $|A| = |C|$, then: $$|A| < |B| \leq |C| = |A|$$ would give $|A| < |A|$, a contradiction.

Comment: Right, sorry I got it mixed up as I was typing. I'll edit it.